# Asp.net web API with angularJS for an E-commerce website

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am a bachelor's undergraduate. For my third year computer project I am hoping to develop a e-commerce website using angularJs and asp.net web API as I have a basic understanding of it. But I have some of questions with my choice.

1) For a E-commerce web app is it a bad decision to develop using above technologies?

2) Will i be able to handle images and other datatypes combined together with text?

3) Would i be able to handle large amounts of Data?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: 1. 100% opinion based. 2 and 3. Sure, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes. Just as much as you could do any other major stack. Depends on how you implement it. E-commerce is a very generic term. There can be e-commerce web apps with 4 pages or 400 pages. These things really determine your tech stack.

2) Yes. Just as much as you could do any other major stack.

3) Yes, but that depends on what DB you use as well.